# Sed to remove everything after "." in file using * command?

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following data.txt:

```
 95 flour.
 47 water.s
 etc..
```

I need to remove everything after the period (`.`) in the file to yield something like this:

```
 95 flour
 47 water
 etc..
```

I have tried the  using these sed commands without success, which yield a blank document:

```
sed "s/'.*//" data.txt > cleaned.txt 
sed 's/\.*//' data.txt > cleaned.txt
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Either escape the `.` with a backslash to get a literal `.`, or use brackets to define a character  class:

```
sed 's/\..*$//' data.txt > cleaned.txt
sed 's/[.].*$//' data.txt > cleaned.txt
```

You tried `'s/\.*//'`, which is "zero or more literal dots", which is different from "literal dot followed by zero or more of anything", i.e. `'s/\..*//'`.  I also added a `$` for good measure.

Answer (score 14):

This is the simplest:

```
sed "s/\..*//"
```

And this is, I think, one of the best ways of doing it (better than pure bash or Python).

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work:

```
sed "s/[.].*//" data.txt > cleaned.txt
```

I would be interested to know how this can be done alternatively in bash and python, if anyone wouldn't mind sharing?

Thanks!

Comment: The non-sed way would be `cut -d. -f1`

Comment: maybe not an issue anymore but if you want to use it in python you can use `str.split(".")[0]`

Comment: All answers indeed are the way to do it in BASH, whether the command line or in a script.